# Distance between a point $X$ and a line $2x-y = 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

I am asked to state a condition for a point $X$ such that the point $X$ is a distance of 10 units from the line $2x-y = 1$, and then find the Cartesian equation of the set of all points $X$ that are a fixed distance $10$ from that line.

I am not sure about the first condition required, but for the cartesian equation would it be
$$
  10\sqrt{5} = |2x-y-1|
$$

which would give me two equations, one being $y = 2x -1 - 10\sqrt{5}$ and the other being $y = 2x -1 + 10\sqrt{5}$ I am not sure which one is the Cartesian equation of all points. I am also unsure of this "condition" they speak of

Comment: The displayed formula is a Cartesian equation that does the job. Alternately we could write it as $500=(2x-y-1)^2$.  That would be more Cartesian, in the sense that the absolute value function cam after Descartes.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure about "state the condition" part

Comment: Maybe they wanted you to say $\frac{|2x-y-1|}{\sqrt{5}}=10$!  As to your question about "which one" it would be wrong to pick out one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "condition" here is the constraint on $X$ that it's distance from $2x-y=1$ is $10$ units. By imposing the condition, you get the locus of $X$.

In this case, the locus is a pair of parallel straight lines parallel to the given line, which you have found out.

The reason why there are two lines is that $X$ can lie on either side of $2x-y=1$, and each line takes into account one side.

Comment: but the condition says "hence", i feel as though it requires more but I don't know what

Comment: @helppls Where is the "hence"? Could you state the complete condition?

Comment: State the condition for the point $X$ to be a distance of 10 units away from the line as above. Hence find the cartesian equation of the set of all points X that are a fixed distance of 10 units from the line.

Comment: @helppls I think they mean that for any point $X$ given by $(x_0,y_0)$, you have to express the condition that the distance of the _point_ from the line is $10$ units. Then, you have to find the _locus_ of all $X$ satisfying this, which is the equation of the pair of straight lines.

Comment: Yeh that makes sense, thanks.